# How I can send an Anonymous Function by Arg? (POSTMAN- WebSocket Request)

Tags: socket.io, postman

I have an event in my Websocket Server who receives a text as first param and an anonymous function as second param. Im using Postman WebSocket request to test it, but in the "new message" section, to sent the arguments, I have only available to set Text, JSON and Binary; however I want to send an anonymous function as param. How I can do it?

[image]

I am currently getting an error from the server, due to this it is receiving the anonymous function as a string.